# Is it possible to use Celery to run an already compiled (py2exe) python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, py2exe

Is it possible to use Celery to run an already compiled (py2exe) python script, if yes, how I can invoke it ?

Answer (score 0):

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()`

should be added to the entry point of the script.